# Routing issue with overloaded Get method in WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have 2 Get methods in Product controller as below:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(string keywordSearch)

[Route("api/Product/{id:long}")]
public IHttpActionResult Get(long id)
```

The following url works:

```
http://localhost:61577/api/Product?keywordSearch=test
http://localhost:61577/api/Product/1
```

This one fails, with message:

```
http://localhost:61577/api/Product/test

{    
"Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:61577/api/Product/test'.",
"MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'Product' that matches the request."
}
```

The WebApiConfig.cs has following configurations:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Please advice, what changes should I make in API function or Config to make that work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to specify the routes in your routes configuration for both the action methods something like:

```
// for number type parameter only
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "IdSearch",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: null,
    constraints: new { id = @"^\d+$" } // Only integers 
);
```

and then register another one for string parameter :

```
// for string parameter overload action route
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "KeyWordSearch",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{keywordSearch}",
    defaults: null
);
```

and in your action declaration apply propery attribute values on string parameter overload one, so that both will look like:

```
[Route("api/Product/{keywordSearch}")]
public IHttpActionResult Get(string keywordSearch)

[Route("api/Product/{id:long}")]
public IHttpActionResult Get(long id)
```

Another way is that you can use the `RoutePrefix` on your Controller class and then the `Route` attribute on your action methods, so that you don't have to duplicate the Prefix of Route on each action method:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/product")] 
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
    [Route("{keywordSearch}")] 
    public IHttpActionResult Get(string keywordSearch)

    [Route("{id:long}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(long id)
}
```

This should keep you going.

Hope it helps!

Comment: **You solution helped me.** I made the following changes in code and it became functional.
1. Added RoutePrefix
`[RoutePrefix("api/product")]`
`public class ProductController : ApiController`

2. Added Route
`[Route("{keywordSearch}")]`
`public IHttpActionResult Get(string keywordSearch)`